# how can I keep all of my outputs centered in Visual Studios as well as my cursor?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am trying to create a sort of an interactive menu (of all my past codes).
How can I keep my output text centered as well as ensure the cursor is centered when a user enters in information?

For centering my outputs, I've just been using a lot of spaces.
As far as centering the cursor, I have no idea where to start.

**currently just using a ton of spaces**

```
Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n                                  Welcome, Please Enter An Encrypted Message Using:");
Console.WriteLine("\r\n                                                     @ For A");
Console.WriteLine("\r\n                                                     # For E");
Console.WriteLine("\r\n                                                     ^ For I");
Console.WriteLine("\r\n                                                     * For O");
Console.WriteLine("\r\n                                                     + For U");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `Console.SetCursorPosition` method with some calculation let the word in the centre.

```
static void SetTextCentre(string s) {
    Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - s.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

then using in `Main` function.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    SetTextCenter("Welcome, Please Enter An Encrypted Message Using:");
    SetTextCenter("@ For A");
    SetTextCenter("# For E");
    SetTextCenter("^ For I");
    SetTextCenter("* For O");
    SetTextCenter("+ For U");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Note**

There are two parameters in `Console.SetCursorPosition` method.

> public static void SetCursorPosition(int left, int top)

if you want to set the centre you need to focus on the first parameter.

- `Console.WindowWidth` get currently console window Width lenght.
- `(Console.WindowWidth - s.Length) / 2` get the word length which in the centre.

Comment: I have multiple classes and methods, should the _SetText_ method be created as a new method, then called upon in the main?

Comment: @RoVaLu Yes you can use it in `Main` method,I add more detail